# disable 'notify' event propagation in user-defined types

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to disable propagation of the `notify` event in user-defined types?

If you take the following example:

```
  define mytype() {
      file { 'myfile': }
      exec { 'myexec': }
  }

  mytype { 'foo': notify => Service['myservice'] }
```

How can I ensure `Service['myservice']` only gets notified when `File['myfile']` changed, but not when `Exec['myexec']` was executed?

I need the event propagation *inside* the defined type, but I only want to propagate it outside when `File['myfile']` changed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more detail on the file and exec would be nice, but here is an answer. Hope it helps...

You could subscribe the file to the service, e.g.

```
service { 'myservice' :
            ensure => running,
            subscribe => File['myfile'],
        }
```

Comment: well, that does not match my question. The reason why I define a type is that I want to *hide* some of the 'magic' going on in background. Subscribing to a file that is not visibly defined anywhere (cause the type defined it) is not a very clean solution, I think. I'd really like to subscribe to the type instead.

There really are no details on the file and exec, because the example I posted is meant to be generic. They are just examples and change depending on what I use the type for. Most often the exec just returns 0 and therefore emits a refresh event.